# Converting nvarchar(255) column to Int takes up more storage space

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a SQL Server database with a certain table, which has around 3 million records. This table has lots of columns with mostly Integer values. I noticed that there are two columns which supposed to be `Integer` too, but for some reason, this column has `nvarchar(255)` datatype. Here I am to fix that!

So I added a new `[int]` column, converted the data, dropped the old `nvarchar(255)` column and renamed the new. All done.

```
ALTER TABLE [SundayManager48].[dbo].[Match]
ADD temp int NULL;

/* Second part */
UPDATE [SundayManager48].[dbo].[Match]
SET temp = TRY_CONVERT(int, [Overal], 110);

/* Third part*/
ALTER TABLE [SundayManager48].[dbo].[Match]
DROP COLUMN [Overal];

/* Fourth part*/
EXEC sp_Rename 'dbo.Match.temp', 'Overal', 'COLUMN';
SELECT * FROM [SundayManager48].[dbo].[Match]
```

Then, just for curiosity, in SQL Server Management studio, I checked the Disk Usage by Table, and noticed that the table size increased from 280MB to 480MB. I just sat there, blinking for a few seconds. I mean, I am not a database expert, but it seems to be very unrealistic that storing an int in datatype Int takes up more space than storing it as a unicode nvarchar(255).

My point was to optimize the database, and reduce the storage. Could anyone database expert point me out, what is going on here?

Another side question, in case the table has 3million records, and like 20 Int columns, changing Int datatypes to Bit would noticeably reduce the database size? These are all small numbers that would fit to a Bit.

Comment: You should always choose the best fit datatype for your data, so if its essentially a bool then yes store it in a bit.

Comment: On the "side question" 20 Int columns is 80 bytes per row. 20 bit columns is 3 bytes per row with space for another 4 bit columns. So you save 77 bytes per row (assuming you aren't using compression) - so potentially you could end up getting quite a lot more rows on a page depending on the width of the other columns

Comment: added new columns and removing old ones doesn't necessarily reorganize the data. You might wanna try to do a table rebuild `alter table yourtable rebuild`.

Comment: Removing a column is a metadata change only. In other words: all that happens is that that column is now ignored in the data if it exists (and is not rewritten into any new pages). Old pages are not modified. So it won't remove them until either all pages are rewritten, or you force that by rebuilding the clustered index.